# Using java.awt.* to create an eventlistener, why does it force you to use public abstract as the class?

Tags: java, swing, events, awt

I am reading about `ActionListener`.
I have added the `implements` keyword and imported the `java.awt.event.*` library.

I followed the example and the oracle Api, but I get this error:

> zx is not abstract and does not override abstract method window deactivated (java.awt.event.windowevent) in java.awt.event.windowlistener.

It is insisting that I make the class `public abstract`.
Does anyone know why I have to do this? 
All the examples I have seen do not make their class abstract.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class zx extends JFrame implements WindowListener, ActionListener {

  public zx() {
    // create window
    super("title 2");
    setSize(100, 100);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    //container
    Container area = getContentPane();

    //layout manager
    GridBagLayout flowManager = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints pos = new GridBagConstraints();
    area.setLayout(flowManager);

    //buttons
    JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
    pos.gridx = 20;
    pos.gridy = 11;
    area.add(button1, pos);

    JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
    pos.gridx = 15;
    pos.gridy = 11;
    area.add(button2, pos);

    JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
    pos.gridx = 4;
    pos.gridy = 4;
    area.add(button3, pos);

    JButton button4 = new JButton("4");
    pos.gridx = 2;
    pos.gridy = 2;
    area.add(button4, pos);

    JButton button5 = new JButton("5");
    pos.gridx = 0;
    pos.gridy = 0;
    area.add(button5, pos);
  }
}
```

Comment: You must make the class abstract **or** implement ***all*** the methods required by the interface(s).

Comment: If you are inheriting a concrete class from an abstract class or an interface, you need to provide implementations of every abstract method. Otherwise your implementing class will also need to be abstract.

Comment: I rolled back your edit because it removed the piece of code that was generating the compilation error. Actually, the code as posted should have multiple compilation errors since no methods in either the `WindowListener` or the `ActionListener` interfaces are implemented. Is this a trimmed-down version of your code?

Comment: no im trying to keep it v simple and follow the book, it is not trimmed down. So its throwing up error due to not finding a method. This is helpful. But why abstract of all the classes, why not just throw up the error instead of suggesting that it has to be abstract? and thank you Michael Myers for doing such a good job.

Comment: `abstract` classes do not need to implement all the interface methods - the unimplemented ones become implicitly `abstract`, and implementing them becomes the responsibility of concrete subclasses. It's just the compiler giving you the two possible ways to solve the error: **either** implement the missing methods, **or** make your class `abstract`.

Answer (score 2):

> all the examples do not set it to abstract.

Well then you shold do what the examples do, which is to actually implement the `WindowListener` and `ActionListener` interfaces.

Start with the simple example from `How to Write an ActionListener` found in the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/handling.html). The try implementing a WindowListener. Then try a class that implements both and ActionListener and a WindowListener.

Also, class names should NOT start with a lower case character. "zx" does not follow conventions. The class name should also be more descriptive. You seem to have a problem following examples. I suggest you take more time to download working examples and then make changes to the working examples when you try to learn a new concept. That way your code will be better structured.

Comment: The is an insulting answer, if i could actually implement this then i wouldn't be reading a book about doing it which does not mention windowlistener at all. You should NOT be commenting on class names, their temporary placeholders for practice purposes only. There are no official examples just what i find via google and they often are too complex for a novice.  You should not be on this forum with your bad attitude, face to face you wouldn't dare be this rude.

Comment: @KyleHarris, `There are no official examples` - the API for any Swing component contains a link to the Swing tutorial. In case you missed that, I also provided you with a link. The Swing tutorial contains all the examples you would need to learn Swing basics. If you read the tutorial and don't understand the example then you ask a specific question about the example.  `You should NOT be commenting on class names` - yes I should. You are asking us to read your code. The code should follow Java conventions. The forum highlights the code based on these conventions.

Comment: `what i find via google and they often are too complex for a novice.` - there are plenty of simple example in the forum. Our answers are usually simple and straight forward. So if you don't understand the suggestion you can link to the answer in your question so we have a better idea of what is confusing you. ` it which does not mention windowlistener ` - Your question states you are reading about an ActionListener, so why does your code even reference a WindowListener? I have given you simple advice to keep your code simple by learning one concept at a time. .

Comment: By the way I could have listed several other problems with your code 1) don't extend JFrame, 2) create the GUI on the EDT, 3) don't use setSize(), instead use pack(), 4) setVisible(...) should be invoked AFTER all components have been added to the frame,. but instead I suggested you use the tutorial examples as a starting point to learn how to code you applications with a better design.

Comment: You offer bad advice and focus on areas that are not relevant to the question. Providing a link to a different example does not help me with my current example. It makes things worse by adding other factors in. I find the oracle API to be almost unreadable as its written by programmers for those who already know how to program.

Comment: The question is very specific, why does it have to be abstract? Ive tried several examples and blueJ will not take it. Even when i directly copy and paste. Your 3rd paragraph is directly contradictory to the text book, you should extend JFrame, i have no idea what EDT is, it says to use setsize(), and no it doesnt have to be invoked AFTER. I dont need a better design, im following the textbooks design. I can improve the finer points such as naming conventions and order objects are created once i have a firm working understanding knowledge. For now i just want to learn.

Comment: @KyleHarris, `why does it have to be abstract?` - it doesn't. You told the compiler that your class `"implements ActionListener"` but your code does NOT do this. You need to implement the `"actionPerformed(...)"` method. If you do this, (like the tutorial examples demonstrate), then the compiler message will go away.  `For now i just want to learn` - which is why I gave you the link to the tutorial. The tutorial examples are better than the book you are using. If you follow the answer given in this forum you will that all 4 suggestions I gave you are recommended.